# Parameter Sweep for Python3.7

Tags: python, bash

Im trying to run a parameter sweep for disease simulation program in python but when i run this the bash program it exports an empty text file, is there an error in my bash script or is it in my python program?

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"
do
    outfile="$arg".txt
    python3.7 diseaseSim.py Y africaMap.csv "$arg" africa.csv > $outfile
done
```

Comment: What arguments do you pass to the script, and what files result?

Comment: In other words, how are you running this bash script?